# Spring Boot Application when deployed as war on standalone tomcat does not read context path from application.properties file

Tags: spring-boot

When i use the same war on embedded tomcat then it works fine and reads the context path from `application.properties` file. But the same war i deploy on standalone tomcat then it does not reads the context Path from `application.properties` file instead it uses deployed war file name as root context.

Using below main class after changing from jar to war

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.it.spc.apihub", "com.it.spc.apihub.api" })
@Configuration
public class Swagger2SpringBoot extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      // Tried all below things too but did not work
      Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put("server.contextPath", "/taas_lite/TaxServlet");
      application.application().setDefaultProperties(map);
        return application.sources(Swagger2SpringBoot.class);//.properties(getProperties());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      /*SpringApplicationBuilder springApplicationBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Swagger2SpringBoot.class);
      springApplicationBuilder.sources(Swagger2SpringBoot.class)
          .properties(getProperties())
          .run(args);*/
// Tried all below things too but did not work
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Swagger2SpringBoot.class);
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("server.contextPath", "/taas_lite/TaxServlet");
        springApplication.setDefaultProperties(map);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
   /* static Properties getProperties() {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("spring.config.location", "classpath:application.properties");
      return props;
   }*/

}
```

application.properties file content

```
server.contextPath=/taas_lite/TaxServlet
server.port=8080
```

Comment: Ofcourse it won't... It doesn't control the server so there is nothing it can do.  That only works with an embedded tomcat. The `server` properties only apply to embedded containers.

Comment: What changes should i make in application so that when deployed on standalone container it behaves as it with embedded one?

Comment: There is no way to apply the `server.*` properties to a non-embedded container. Those properties correspond to Tomcat (or whatever container you use) configuration, configure your tomcat appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Would you please let me know what changes i have to make in standalone tomcat's server.properties file? Please provide snippet for the change in server.properties file.